# Getting incorrect parsed date when using SimpleDateTimeFormatter with time zone

Tags: java, datetime

I've the following code:

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    String s2 = "Mon Oct 19 19:52:21 IST 2015";
    System.out.println(format.parse(s2));
```

I expected that the code would print "Mon Oct 19 07:22:21 PDT 2015", but to my surprise it printed "Mon Oct 19 10:52:21 PDT 2015". I can see that "IST" is a valid time zone for "z". However, the following code worked fine:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    String s2 = "Mon Oct 19 19:52:21 GMT+05:30 2015";
    System.out.println(format.parse(s2));
```

Please help.

Comment: Both code snippets throw a `ParseException: unparsable date` for me.

Comment: @ESala No, they should work fine.

Comment: I tested both, and **for me**, they both throw the above exception. Maybe someone else can test it.

Comment: @ESala: use   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).. you are missing Locale

Comment: @Esala I tested the code using ideone.com and that works fine.

Comment: @Robadob I added the `Locale.ENGLISH` as he said later, and now it works for me as well.

Comment: @awsome locale is not really required and it prints the same even if I explicitly give it.

Comment: yes because his timezone is different, so he would have to use different symbol for day which is EEE for english

Comment: @geekprogrammer explicit locale is recommended and even required if the system locale is not English (your system is English, but not with ESala). Keep in mind that day-of-week and month ("Mon", "Oct") are written in English in your example.

Comment: Are you sure "IST" is supported? I just tried to do this: `TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("IST"));` and it threw exception `ZoneRulesException: unknown time-zone ID: IST`.

Comment: @ESala "IST" is not a timezone identifier (tz-id) but a timezone name (exactly an abbreviated timezone name). The `ZoneId`-code can only accept identifiers not names. And keep in mind that "IST" might stand for India Standard Time or for Israel etc. It is not unique hence dangerous to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using `IST` is dangerous as it could stand for Indian or Israel ST. 
Assuming you meant Indian ST, try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    String s2 = "Mon Oct 19 19:52:21 IST 2015";
    System.out.println(format.parse(s2));
```

Also, follow suggestion from @Meno's answer

Comment: I'm note explcitly using IST actually; I've a remote system which pushes these dates to my program and it is sending like that. So to conclude, I don't have control over the time that is coming to my program. I only the format before, in my case it is EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy.

Comment: Can you clarify `remote system ...sending like that`? I am a bit confused. The code I have posted is the same as yours with one extra line about `setTimeZone(...)`

Comment: I've a system with log4j which is sending the date like "Mon Oct 19 19:52:21 IST 2015" to my program and I need to convert that date to my systems time and print.  Only thing that I before is that the remore system is configured with the dateformat "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", so I'm using the same to parse at my end.

Comment: Of course, the timezone should not be set on the parser but on the printer - see the intention of my answer.

Comment: But, unfortunately,  I don't know the remote system's TimeZone information. Now I understand the problem. Unless the remote system gives the time zone inforamtion, we may not get the desired parsed value.

Answer (score 0):

The code expression

```
System.out.println(format.parse(s2));
```

always prints your instant/moment (an object of type `java.util.Date`) in your system timezone which is apparently PDT. You implicitly apply the method `toString()`on `java.util.Date`. Use a dedicated formatter like `SimpleDateFormat` and set the timezone on this formatter to achieve the desired result.

Finally you need two formatters, one for parsing and one for printing.