# How to resolve Unparseable date error

Tags: java

I am receiving date from the RSS Feed in the below format 
Fri Oct 23 11:07:08 IST 2015 which i am trying to convert it into 
`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format .

I have tried this way

```
public class ConvertDate {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
    {
        String passedate = "Fri Oct 23 11:07:08 IST 2015";
    String res= convertdate(passedate);
    System.out.println(res);
    }
    public static String convertdate(String recivieddate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        Date date = in.parse(recivieddate);
        SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        String newdate = out.format(date);
        return newdate;
    }
}
```

But i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Oct 23 11:07:08 IST 2015"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at ConvertDate.convertdate(ConvertDate.java:20)
    at ConvertDate.main(ConvertDate.java:12)
```

Could you please let em know how to resolve this

Comment: Well, your format has the year where the day-of-month is, instead of the end.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date pattern does not match the input. Try change the line

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

to

```
 SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your date has the format `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` with an english local.
This parses the date correctly:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
        .parse("Fri Oct 23 11:07:08 IST 2015");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));  //or Asia/Jerusalem
    String s2 = "Fri Oct 23 11:07:08 IST 2015";
    Date date = in.parse(s2);

    SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    out.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    System.out.println(out.format(date));
```

Output:

> 2015-10-23 11:07
>   Also, note the `setTimeZone`. IST can either stand for Indian ST or Israel ST so it would be better if you specify which time zone you really want.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217128/getting-incorrect-parsed-date-when-using-simpledatetimeformatter-with-time-zone/33217868#33217868) for  `IST` ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

First check your actual date which you need to work .. In my case

String day="date:10/01/2018";(In selenium need to get it from web page so i got the above string from page)

```
SimpleDateFormat  df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date ndate = df.parse(day);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.setTime(ndate);
         cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
         Date DDueDate1= cal.getTime();
         day =df.format(DDueDate1);
```

When am working on this i got unparsable error....

So the day string contains some part of characters . So just remove those characters from string by using **day.split(":");** String day1=day[1];
just give this day1 string in parse(); Now the  updated code like as below..

```
SimpleDateFormat  df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date ndate = df.parse(day1);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.setTime(ndate);
         cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
         Date DDueDate1= cal.getTime();
         day =df.format(DDueDate1);
```