# How can i convert this time (GMT Format) to IST Time?

Tags: java

I am getting a time in GMT format

for example 4:40pm

I have tried it this way

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
             String time = convertTimetoIST("4:40pm");
                System.out.println(time);
        }
        public static String convertTimetoIST(String recivieddate) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mma");
            in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
            return in.toString();
        }
    }
```

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: Don't you need to know the source timezone? I would use one `SimpleDateFormat` instance bound to the source TZ for parsing the `recivieddate` and another instance for formatting it to the destination TZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code for the same

```
in.parse(recivieddate).toString()
```

Comment: Thanks , but i am not getting the time in IST format .

Comment: What is the result you are getting with this code at your end

Comment: Its printing object java.text.SimpleDateFormat@7eef8d47

Comment: did you change the return statement as `return in.parse(recivieddate).toString();` in the `convertTimetoIST` method?

Comment: Vivek , when i ran the program i am getting output as Thu Jan 01 04:40:00 IST 1970
where as it should be 11:10am know for the given time ??

Answer (score 1):

IST is ambiguous as it can stand for both Indian ST and Israel ST.

Try this:

```
in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
```

Also, you need to return using Vivek's answer. I would recommend using two different instances - one for parsing and one for formatting.

Also check this:

[Getting incorrect parsed date when using SimpleDateTimeFormatter with time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217128/getting-incorrect-parsed-date-when-using-simpledatetimeformatter-with-time-zone/33217868#33217868)